# Files can not be uploaded in my webpage

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

i wanted to make my webpage to upload images and save them in a folder or the database but  after lots of trying and changed my code ,googling  and switching from wampserver to easyphp then to apachserver non of them worked for me , my webpage still display '403 error forbidden' even after i tried solutions  i found here most of them consist of changes in config file but non of them worked i can't understand this problem   and this is my code that is supposed to work

```
$dir_name=dirname(__FILE__)."/Uploaded/";
$path=$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] ;
$name=$_FILES['upload']['name'] ; 
$size=$_FILES['upload']['size'] ;
$type=$_FILES['upload']['type'] ;
$error=$_FILES['upload']['error'] ;
move_uploaded_file($path,$dir_name.$name);
echo "off" ;

echo "error in uploading";

?>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" value="choose" name="upload" />
<input type="submit" value="update" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: What do the logfiles of the webserver tell you?

Comment: Check this part `$PHP_SELF` It would be `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`

Comment: even after this change but what does $PHP_SELF refers to ? i think to display the error which is "403 error forbidden access" and now it's not displayed after changing it to $_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]  and again no uploaded image and no saved image even after switching the machine did you try it with later and it works ? @Saty

Comment: i don't know how to read them what should they contain @selten98 ?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed some codes. and i hope it works fine now.and the main thing is $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; to take the same page address.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['upload']))
    {
    $dir_name=dirname(__FILE__)."/Uploaded/";
    $path=$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] ;
    $name=$_FILES['upload']['name'] ;
    $size=$_FILES['upload']['size'] ;
    $type=$_FILES['upload']['type'] ;
    $error=$_FILES['upload']['error'] ;
    move_uploaded_file($path,$dir_name.$name);
    echo "off" ;

    echo "error in uploading";
    }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" value="choose" name="upload" />
        <input type="submit" value="update" name="submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: where do you find the images @Abhinav ? because for me no displayed images on the webpage nor stored in the folder

Comment: you need to create a folder called uploaded. dirname(__FILE__) returns the current file path so you can create a path in there or you can crate a directory in there dynamically using  mkdir() in php.

Comment: do i need to creat another directory or folder in the code too ? i already have this Uploaded folder and i can't find anything in it could you help me more please !

Comment: any error showing??
this php page and uploaded directory is in same path?